# Ag-grid: duplicate node id 107 detected from getRowNodeId callback , this could cause issues in your grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am going to do live data streaming on ag-grid datatable, so I used  DeltaRowData for gridOptions and added getRowNodeId method as well which return unique value 'id'.
After all, I got a live update result on my grid table within some period I set, but some rows are duplicated so I can notice total count is a bit increased each time it loads updated data. The question title is warning message from browser console, I got bunch of these messages with different id number. Actually it is supposed not to do this from below [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#delta-row-data). This is supposed to detect dups and smartly added new ones if not exist. Ofc, there are several ways to get refreshed data live, but I chose this one, since it says it helps to persist grid info like selected rows, current position of scroll on the grid etc. I am using vanilla js, not going to use any frameworks.
How do I make live data updated periodically without changing any current grid stuff? There is no error on the code, so do not try to speak about any bug. Maybe I am wrong with current implementation, Anyway, I want to know the idea or hear any implementation experience on this.

```
let gridOptions = {
    ....
    deltaRowDataMode: true,
    getRowNodeId = (data) => {
        return data.id; // return the property you want set as the id.
    }
}

fetch(loadUrl).then((res) => {
   return res.json()
}).then((data) => {
  gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
})

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get:

> **duplicated node warning**

it means your `getRowNodeId()` has 1 value for 2 different rows.

here is part [from source](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/9565c219b6210aa85fa833c929d0728f9d163a91/community-modules/client-side-row-model/dist/es6/clientSideRowModel/clientSideNodeManager.js#L263):

```
if (this.allNodesMap[node.id]) {
        console.warn("ag-grid: duplicate node id '" + node.id + "' detected from getRowNodeId callback, this could cause issues in your grid.");
}
```

so try to check your data again.

*if u 100% sure there is an error not related with your data - cut oof the private data, create a plinkr/stackblitz examples to reproduce your issue and then it would be simpler to check and help you.*

Comment: yes, there was an issue with duplicated ids in my datasource since I joined several tables so I should have made an unique field with combining id fields from those tables. not just using an id field from a table. thanks for your information